# Python how to pass multiple arguments as a list instead of passing them separately

Tags: python, sql, list

I am trying to insert into an sql database and have 20 different arguments that I need to pass as '?'. I have all these parameters in a list and am wondering if there is a way or a shortcut that can automate passing these arguments instead of writing all of them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP249 (the Python DB API 2.0 Specification) already defines that passing parameters to the `execute` method already allows a sequence or mapping:

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to
> variables in the operation. Variables are specified in a
> database-specific notation

Because this is the case, you can take your list `my_list` and simply pass it as is to the `execute` method:

```
connection = my_db_driver.connect('connection_string')
my_cursor = connection.cursor()
my_parameter_list = ['lesko borashvili', 122121211]
my_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE my_user = ? and my_order = ?', my_parameter_list)
```

Comment: `p = ['FName','LName', 'lekso', 'borashvili']
 self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Names(?,?) VALUES (?,?)", p)
 self.con.commit()
`
I am getting the following error : The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Pa_RaM000'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again. (-1507) (SQLExecDirectW)")